# Nullable Enum nullable type question

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, nullable

I get the following compilation error with the following source code:

Compilation Error:

Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'MyEnum'

Source Code

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1, Value2, Value3
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() {}
    public MyEnum? MyClassEnum { get; set; }
}

public class Main()
{
   object x = new object();

   MyClass mc = new MyClass()
   {
        MyClassEnum = Convert.IsDBNull(x) : null ? 
            (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.ToString(), true)
   };
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullable type issue with ?: Conditional Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/nullable-type-issue-with-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you just need to cast the result of `Enum.Parse` to `MyEnum?`. This is the case with nullable ints at least. E.g.:

```
int? i;
i = shouldBeNull ? null : (int?) 123;
```

So:

```
MyClassEnum = Convert.IsDBNull(x)
    ? null
    : (MyEnum?) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.ToString(), true)
```

Comment: MyClassEnum must also be nullable (obviously).

Comment: To be clear this only happens because you are using the ternary operator

Answer (score 11):

There is a syntax error in your code: the position of ':' and '?' must be exchanged:

```
MyClassEnum = Convert.IsDBNull(x) ? null : 
            (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.ToString(), true)
```

BTW:

as far as I know, the recommended way is to use a enum-element named 'None' instead of a Nullable enum, e.g:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    None, Value1, Value2, Value3
}
```

and

```
MyClassEnum = Convert.IsDBNull(x) ? MyEnum.None : 
            (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you will just need to cast the result to (MyEnum?) rather than (MyEnum)?