# Why doesn't the ternary operator find cast type depending on value being looked for?

Tags: c#

A question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772421/771665) raised a question for me:

Ternary operations in c#, say `x = y ? a : b`, use the type of either `a` or `b` to determine the type of the ternary expression. Why doesn't it use the type of `x`? In any given  situation, isn't there an expected return type that it can use?

EDIT: For the sake of clarity, when I say

> Why doesn't it use the type of `x`?

I suppose I mean

> Why doesn't it first try to use the type of `x`?

As the documentation states:

- If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the
  conditional expression.
- Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (Section
  6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
- Otherwise, if an implicit conversion
  (Section 6.1) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the
  type of the conditional expression.
- Otherwise, no expression type can
  be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Could this process start with:

- If the resolution type is unambiguous, then it is the type of the conditional expression.

Comment: Method overloading in C# does not use return value. Why should operators be different?

Comment: What if `x` is declared `dynamic` or `var`?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff then VS will say that the type cannot be inferred

Comment: At least the original question used a better name for the operator. Calling it "the ternary operator" because C# only defines one such operator is a sloppy shorthand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "In any given situation, isn't there an expected return type that it
>   can use?"

No. Consider for example:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(y ? a : b);
```

There are multiple overloads of the `ToString` method that takes different data types. The compiler needs to know what the type of the expression is to know which overload to use.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, the "target" type as asked by the Op would have to be the type of the argument expected by the function... which is overloaded. Even if you have rules for something like taking the broadest overload possible, that would be the type "Object", and who wants that?

Comment: That makes sense, but even in the instance where `x` is ambiguous, it seems like the normal process could be used (try `a`, then `b`).