# Syntax confusion in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

So I'm looking at a project that calls a function I've never seen before, and I'm only beginning my familiarity with C# syntax. I've worked with Python and Javascript for some weeks now, and I'm closer to experienced with them, but this syntax still baffles me.

```
private static void GENERIC_FUNCTION_NAME(string[] args)
    {
        GENERIC_OBJECT_NAME.OTHER_GENERIC_FUNCTION_NAME();

        string path = args == null || args.Length == 0 ?
            @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH" :
            args[1];

        var GENERIC_VARIABLE_NAME = new GENERIC_OBJECT_NAME();
        GENERIC_VARIABLE_NAME.Open(path);
    }
```

I'm confused by the syntax of the parameters of this function.

You see, this function was written in a C# console application and has lots of C++ components in the project that do the work it's meant to trigger. But I've been told to build a GUI for it that achieves the same goal here. I'm not even sure what gets passed as `args`... Because I don't see it anywhere in the script next to this code, which is the only function inside the `Program.cs` that was written when I got the files to work with.

Because of this, I can't make a button connect to this function. I don't know how to integrate `object sender, EventArgs e` so that the button can be connected (and if I do it directly, ie, "`(object sender, EventArgs e, string[] args)`", I get an error. What am I doing wrong? And how might I integrate the function and make it button addressable?

EDIT: I've moved the questions regarding the ternary operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144553/introducing-myself-to-ternary-operators) for future readers' sanity. If you would like, please repost your input on this, as you guys have already helped me here on it.

Comment: For the last question, it's a `ternary operator` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: So following the structure of `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`, it follows that the condition is `string path = args == null || args.Length == 0`, and the `first` and `second` expressions are `@"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH"` and `args[1]`?

Comment: Good to see those developers didn't believe in naming conventions for methods :)

Comment: Even knowing this, I am still confused by the condition. What is `string path = args == null || args.Length == 0` saying? Is it something like `if path (of type string) = args OR if args.Length == 0`? What is the `== null` saying?

Comment: the `args` of the main function contains the text the user entered on the command line when starting the program; see [Command Line Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Python has similar behavior, although somewhat more hidden; you can access the command line args through `sys.argv`

Comment: `string path = args == null || args.Length == 0` Boils down to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(args)`... and then assigns to `path`

Comment: @DavidL This code is from my workplace-- For privacy's sake I've just renamed the names with "GENERIC" names.

Comment: For the first part of your question, if you double-click on your button (assuming you're using Visual Studio), it will automatically make a click callback.  In that callback, you can invoke GENERIC_FUNCTION_NAME.  I'm not sure where you would get the string[] from, though.  We need more info for that.

Comment: @JWarner112 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772366/conditional-operator-with-nullable-type-casting has some info on the ?: conditional operator.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein GENERIC_FUNCTION_NAME is obviously `Main`

Comment: to complete @ScottMermelstein comment. The commandline args in a non console app can be found in [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

Comment: Could you split your problem into separate manageable questions? Your question is currently very broad and has almost no value to future readers.

Comment: @lesderid I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your method was called `Main`, and is by default the only method in `Program.cs`

This main method takes arguments when the program is executed, such as running through CMD with optional arguments such as `app.exe -myArg`, and is translated into a string array. *See more on [command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).*

If not, you can right click the method name, and *View All References*, or *Find Call hierarchy* to figure out what might be calling it.

For your second issue...
What you are seeing is a special conditional operator, the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). (And [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary) is a nice tutorial)

It is used like so:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Basically if the statement is true, the first expression is executed, if not, the second is. Generally speaking it is a small shortcut for `if/else` blocks, and should be used for only small statements. Nesting the ternary operator is largely frowned upon.

So if `args == null || args.Length == 0`
Then `path = @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH"`, if not, it equals `args[1]`

It is equivalent to your standard `if` block

```
string path;
if(args == null || args.Length == 0)
{
   path = @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH";
}
else
{
   path = args[1];
}
```

Now that that is taken care of, if you double click your button in the designer, it will take you (or generate) a method that is executed when the button is clicked. From there you can call this method with it's arguments (Which if it is `main`, I'm not sure why you would be doing this. But I'm not sure if I quite understand the issue)

Comment: You're exactly right about this method-- it was called `Main` and it was the only method in `Program.cs`. I'm not at all used to anything outside of basic demo programs in Visual Studio, so I don't know where this is supposed to go in my project if I want to "create an equivalent GUI" based on it. I have another `Program.cs`, but no idea how to properly merge this sample code with my own `Form1`. You don't happen to know what I would want to do in that case, do you?

Comment: Could you explain more on the layout of your solution? Your Form1 also has its own class.

Comment: My employer gave me a solution with four different projects in it: One is a C++ .dll that wraps zlib methods used throughout. One is a C# interop code that handles a generic type of storage file we access. One is a C# library that extracts data from a specific type of that aforementioned storage file. A final one is a simplified console app, from which this code copied/pasted, and it gives an example of calling the libraries previously established to inspect a stream.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to write a GUI that can call to these libraries but I don't know how to do that when my example is a console app, and I'm expected to access the same libraries in a Windows form application.

Answer (score 3):

i can help with the syntax issue.

string path is equal to either @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH"  OR (:)  args[1]

to determine which one if args == null OR args.length == 0 then go with  @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH"  if not then go with args[1]
it is the same as the following

```
if(args == null || args.Length == 0)
{
    string path = @"C:\GENERIC\SYSTEM\PATH" ;
}
else{
    string path = args[1];
}
```

Here is some further reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: As an aside, I'm _guessing_ you'll want `path` declared outside the `if/else` blocks though as it will not be accessible outside otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for this! However, for clarity, I split the questions and put the ternary operator question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144553/introducing-myself-to-ternary-operators). If you could just repost this answer there, I'll be able to vote on it.

Comment: it was more for demonstration of what the ternary operator meant. but yes you are correct

Comment: its ok you can mark one of the many other answers! go with @Cyral he seems eager!

Comment: No problem it was my pleasure