# Conditional Operator with DateTime? won't compile

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nullable, conditional-operator

Can anyone tell me why this won't compile?

```
DateTime? completedDT;
bool completed = false;
completedDT= completed ? DateTime.Now : null;
```

I would have thought that as it was writing to a nullable object (`DateTime?`) the use of null would be acceptable. Instead I get this error:

> Error  19  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'null'

Comment: capital DT vs dt in completedDT ?

Comment: You have to explicitly cast one of the operand in conditional statement to `DateTime?` like `completedDT = completed ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?) null;`

Comment: Cast the right hand side to `DateTime?`

Comment: Sorry fixed that. It was a typo when I was typing the question.

Comment: Also see this question for better explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772366/conditional-operator-with-nullable-type-casting

Comment: David Christopher Reynolds - I've updated title - feel free to update/revert, but keep in mind that "comparison" usually mean `==`/`!=`, and you are asking about `?:` - "conditional operator" which is commonly called "ternary operator" (since it is the only "ternary" operator in many languages like c/C++/Java/JavaScript/C#...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

```
completedDT= completed ? DateTime.Now : new DateTime?();
completedDT= completed ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?)null;
completedDT= completed ? DateTime.Now : default(DateTime?);
```

Thanks at C.Evenhuis for the `default()` option.

Comment: A third option would be `default(DateTime?)`.

Comment: You can also cast `DateTime.Now` to `datetime?` (but don't ask me if there's a perf. impact)