# Why I can't to this assignment?

Tags: c#, datetime, null

This is my code:

```
DateTime? test;
test = ((objectParsed.birthday != null) ? DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday : null));
```

Why can I not set that variable to `null`?

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses in that code, which makes it hard to understand.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Is this a TERNARY operator with ONE parameter???

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: fixed. I cannot do a implicit conversion between DateTime and null

Comment: Your question in the article differs from the title: can vs. can't

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullable type issue with ?: Conditional Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/nullable-type-issue-with-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from anything to do with `Nullable<T>` (in this case, `DateTime?`), the error is happening specifically here:

```
((objectParsed.birthday != null) ? DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday : null))
```

Note that there's no mention of a nullable `DateTime` in this code.  And before the result of this code is assigned to a nullable `DateTime`, this code by itself needs to be evaluated.  It can't be, because of the error you're seeing.

The operator being used (`: ?`) needs to be able to infer types from all arguments to the operation, and those types need to be able to match.  Here you're passing it a `DateTime` and `null` which can't be matched.  Try casting one of the arguments:

```
((objectParsed.birthday != null) ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday : null))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set null in this case because ternary operator must return values same types
try this:

```
test = (objectParsed.birthday != null) ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday): null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 test = ((objectParsed.birthday != null) ? DateTime.Parse((string)objectParsed.birthday): null;
```

Explanation: the structure of a ternary operator is:

```
variable = (condition)?(value if yes):(value if no);
```