# Fetch blob into a linq object

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012

I'm usually using linq syntax to fetch data from tables but in this case when fetching blobs I'm having trouble with linq not able to handle large blobs.

So therefore I'm trying to fetch blobs using this way:

```
        var li = new List<linq_table1>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT blob FROM table1";
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new linq_table1;
                    row.blob = reader[0] as System.Data.Linq.Binary;
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

linq_table1 is a dbml table of table1 which only contains one column with the type varbinary(blob). `reader[0] as System.Data.Linq.Binary` though returns null when the row in the table contains a blob.

Comment: try `(byte[])reader["blob"]`

Comment: Thanks it worked! Would you mind posting an answer so I can accept it? Also if my table1 got a datetime column how do I cast reader[1] (containing the datetime but in the type object) to DateTime(sql)? Trying to cast to System.DateTime gives the error: `The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.DateTime' is a non-nullable value type)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for

```
(byte[])reader["blob"];
```

Further reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Further to your comment you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/nullable-type-issue-with-conditional-operator)